# NoSuchMethodError org.restlet.routing.Virtualhost.attach

Tags: restlet

I am getting this error with the new restlet repository.  It used to work: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.restlet.routing.VirtualHost.attach(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/restlet/Restlet;)Lorg/restlet/routing/Route;  at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent.attachUriPatternToRestlet(RestletComponent.java:286)

I have an ivy dependency for restlet-2.1.1

I am using a restlet in a camel route

Comment: The code that is being executed when that error occurs would help people help you solve your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the Camel extension for Restlet does rely on the same version as your Restlet dependency in Ivy (2.1.1) or at least the same branch (2.1.x)?