# Apache Camel Restlet is not working

Tags: java, apache-camel, restlet

I don't know which library is missing to include Camel RESTlet component. Included `camel-restlet-2.11.1.jar` and `org.restlet.jar` from restlet-jse-2.1.2 but I am getting

```
2013-07-12 09:37:28,021 [main           ] ERROR ContextLoader                  - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.restlet.routing.VirtualHost.attach(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/restlet/Restlet;)Lorg/restlet/routing/Route;
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent.attachUriPatternToRestlet(RestletComponent.java:300)[camel-restlet-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent.connect(RestletComponent.java:139)[camel-restlet-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletEndpoint.connect(RestletEndpoint.java:86)[camel-restlet-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
```

There has been a similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323830/nosuchmethoderror-org-restlet-routing-virtualhost-attach) but no answer to this question.

Comment: The link you posted has this as a comment: "Are you sure that the Camel extension for Restlet does rely on the same version as your Restlet dependency..."

What are your dependency versions for camel and restlet?

Comment: @SheenaArtrip Updated my answer with versions.

Answer (score 1):

camel-restlet version 2.11.1 requires restlet 2.0.15 but you have included restlet 2.1 . I'm sure there are API differences between the two, though the Restlet javadoc for 2.0 is really hard to find so I can't confirm that:

org.restlet.routing.VirtualHost.attach(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/restlet/Restlet;)Lorg/restlet/routing/Route;

doesn't exist.